# How to parsing the String xml in java?

Tags: java, xml

I am getting the https request  string as Dynamic XML format.The XML assigned to String. String contains following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xxf:id="0f81046cee210b5b64db5706b6fe79f986fb539b">
        <section-1 xxf:id="e7d2bb4ac261e77159fc236e7fd922c3540756f8">
                        <control-1 xxf:id="35a9efc3d88c7ec36a22de72034599f47483c43e">Sree</control-1>
                        <control-2 xxf:id="06744b5c8c6cc153ce8e79cb3b1ca501dc98424a">India</control-2>
                        <control-4 xxf:id="16662b83b4580c255f6b1ae3dfee016ac7761de5">9876543210</control-4>
                </section-1>

        <section-2 xxf:id="e7d2bb4ac261e77159fc236e7fd922c3540756f8">
                        <control-5 xxf:id="35aw4r3d88c7ec36a22de72034599f47483c43e">David</control-5>
                        <control-3 xxf:id="79cb3b1ca501dc98424a06744b5c8c6cc153ce8e">America</control-3>
                        <control-6 xxf:id="f6b1ae3dfee016ac7761de516662b83b4580c255">9876556789</control-6>
                </section-2>

        ........
        ........
    </form>
```

I need to get dynamic ids(control-1,control-2,control-3 ...) and values in the String XML.

Now I need get the following ids(unique) and with respective values in the String.

```
control-1=Sree,
control-2=India,
control-4=9876543210,

control-5=David,
control-3=America,
control-6=9876556789,
```

**Note:**  following tags are generated by dynamically and unique.

```
 <section->  and <Control->
```

Comment: Please show us, what you already have and tell us where you have issues. If you need a starting point, please go to the tutorial and have a look at StAX: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Jsoup:

```
for(Element e : Jsoup.parse(xml).select("form > * > *")){
   System.out.println(e.tagName() + "=" + e.text() + ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [STAX from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) to parse XML files.

You must take file, reader and factory

```
XMLStreamReader r = null;
FileInputStream fi = null;

    try {
        XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        fi = new FileInputStream("filePath");
        r = f.createXMLStreamReader(fi);
```

And then iterate over the reader:

```
        while (r.hasNext()) {
            int event = r.next();

            switch (event) {

            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                if ("section-1".equals(r.getLocalName())) { 
                    while (r.hasNext() && !exit) {
                        event = r.next();
                        switch (event) {

                        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                        if ("control-1".equals(r.getLocalName())) { 
                            // r.getElementText contains Sree
                        } 
                    }
                }
           }
```

And so on....

Comment: Consider to use the NIO.2 File API and try-with-resources.

Comment: Also consider to use the Iterator API instead of the Cursor API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/api.html